# Imagemagick: Create a diff image with transparent background

Tags: imagemagick

I want to create a diff from two images, that can be applyed on top of first image, resulting on the same second image.

I'm trying to do like this:

```
convert -composite -compose difference img1.png img2.png img-diff.png
```

The resulting `img-diff.png` shows a black background where `img1.png` is equal to `img2.png`.

I want to generate the diff with a transparent background, to allow me to create an animation by combining it with the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `-transparent black` before the output filename. You may, or may not, want to add a `-fuzz 5%` to make near black also become transparent.

So, in concrete terms, if you start off with these two images

[image]
[image]

and you then run this command:

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg -compose difference -composite -fuzz 5% -transparent black out.png
```

you end up with this (it shows transparent as white because SO uses JPEGs which can't show transparency).

I think the problem with your (valiant) attempt is that you need to set `-compose` first to tell IM *how* to compose the images before it actually goes ahead and does it with `-composite` and also you were missing the `-transparent black` part.

[image]